# Modify application instruction in PIN

Tags: c++, c, assembly, intel-pin

I am using Intel PIN to modify an instruction in my application. I am using the Safecopy() example from this link as a reference:

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/81205/Pin/html/index.html#SafeCopy

I have the following sample C program:

```
int main()
{
    asm(".byte 0x16");
    return 0;
}
```

0x16 is illegal in x86_64 and when I run the executable it displays the following error as expected:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have a pintool which takes the above executable as input and modifies the illegal instruction 0x16 to do something else.

My Pintool is as follows:

```
#include "pin.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool", "o", "test.out","This pin tool simulates ULI");

FILE * op;

//====================================================================
// Analysis Routines
//====================================================================

VOID analysis_routine(VOID *ip, UINT32 size) 
{ 

    fprintf(op,"16 came to analysis routine\n\n");
}


//====================================================================
// Instrumentation Routines
//====================================================================

VOID Instruction(INS ins, void *v) 
{

    UINT8 opcodeBytes[15];

    UINT64 fetched = PIN_SafeCopy(&opcodeBytes[0],(void *)INS_Address(ins),INS_Size(ins));

    if (fetched != INS_Size(ins))
        fprintf(op,"\nBad\n");

    else 
    {
        if(opcodeBytes[0]==0x16)
        {

            fprintf(op,"\n16 came to instrumentation routine\n");

            INS_InsertCall( ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)analysis_routine, IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_UINT64, INS_Size(ins) , IARG_END);
            INS_Delete(ins);
        }
    }
}

VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v) 
{
}

INT32 Usage() {
    PIN_ERROR("This Pintool failed\n" + KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() + "\n");
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    op = fopen("test.out", "w");

    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) 
        return Usage();

    PIN_InitSymbols();
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);
    PIN_StartProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

According to my understanding the instrumentation routine Instruction is executed everytime a new instruction is encountered and according to my code, the analysis routine is called before the instruction is executed as I am using the IPOINT_BEFORE argument in my instrumentation function to invoke the analysis routine. I am thus checking for my opcode and if it is 0x16, then I am invoking my analysis routine and deleting my original instruction. Since the insturction was illegal and it has been deleted, my trace should proceed futher without any problems.

However even with this logic, it seems my illegal instruction is being executed and my program crashes and gives the same illegal instruction error. I am not able to understand the problem as I seem to be deleting the instruction before it executes and I am using the same example from the Pin tutorial.

Any ideas if I am invoking anything wrong? Also please correct me if I am wrong anywhere above. According to my understanding the instrumentation routine is invoked before the instruction executes and thus I can modify the instruction that time also. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you successfully replacing the right byte at the right address? Are you certain you are only replacing the one byte that is causing you trouble? Are you only replacing that single byte an no other byte pattern? 0x16 may not be a legal instruction by itself but how are you making sure it is not being interpreted as part of a larger instruction?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's going wrong here, but here's what I'd do: I would start with printing far more information about the instruction in the instrumentation routine.

- How long is it?
- What address did this instruction have? Print the address of main() in the test program to see if the two are close to one another.
- What are the other instruction bytes? Do they happen to be bytes matching the instructions that follow the illegal bytes?

Aditionally:

- Make sure the output file is flushed after every print, to ensure that the illegal instruction failure doesn't happen to mask your debug prints
- I recommend catching the SIGILL signal that your program is probably getting and making sure it's happening in the same place with and without Pin.

Comment: I get the instruction size using INS_Size(ins). I get the address using INS_Address(ins). When I copy INS_Size(ins) bytes from the pointer at the instruction address, I get all the instruction bytes. They match as I have checked with the disassembly of my instruction trace.

Comment: There are other checks that I recommend that you do

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that INS_Delete() is called at instrumentation time, i.e. before the instruction is actually executed, but also before the call of your instrumentation routine. The order in which events occur is as follow:

```
INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)analysis_routine, ...);
INS_Delete(ins);
analysis_routine(); /* <= BOOM ! ins had been deleted just before... */
```

When INS_Delete(ins) is called, you need to remove all the instrumentation that goes with it otherwise your tool is not coherent. Assuming the instrumentation remains, the instruction that will be associated with the instrumentation routine will not be the one expected, hence the crash.

To understand this better (which is not easy to get right the first time) you might want to read again how [pin works](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/index.html#Pin).

**EDIT:** According to some official pintools packaged with the tool (see comments below), the *instrument then delete* pattern is a regular pattern of PIN.

Comment: I haven't used PIN at all, but I'm curious.  Why exactly is it a problem to call `analysis_routine()` after using `INS_Delete()`?  What exactly does INS_Delete() do?  Assume that people reading the answer don't understand how to use PIN correctly, otherwise they wouldn't be having this problem.  At least link to the part of the docs that explains it, as well as pointing out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I updated the answer accordingly, I hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, so `INS_Delete(ins)` deletes the instrumentation, rather than removing the instruction from what will actually be executed.  Yup, reading documentation is a good idea, instead of hoping functions do what you want based on the name. :P  This pretty much answers all of @Rohit's string of questions.

Comment: It is not what the manual says, but you should assume that your instrumentation is not valid anymore in this case, and that it will be undefined behavior. What instruction do you think will come up in the instrumentation routine if you have deleted it... ? (I updated my answer one more time :-) )

Comment: The OP here is trying to use PIN to simulate a CPU that uses `0x16` as an opcode for a new instruction.  Can PIN do that?  i.e. run some handler function and *not* #UD / SIGILL on the `0x16` byte in the instruction stream?  Anyway, this is why they're trying to "delete" the instruction so it doesn't run.

Comment: I have never done that, but I believe the following API shall be used instead (for expert only): https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/group__INS__MOD__API__GEN__IA32.html

Comment: @Heyji I'm not sure where you go the idea that you can't insert analysis functions to deleted instructions - this approach is very much in use in the samples provided with the Pin kit. See for example ``source\tools\Tests\emu.cpp``

Comment: In fact, even the example OP is referring to uses the "instrument then delete" pattern.

Comment: @nitzanms: you are right, according to this example, the instrument then delete pattern should work. I got this idea from my own reasoning, because the manual does not says anything about when the instruction is deleted. I assumed it is deleted during instrumentation. And if so, assuming the instrumentation routine is still set up (which does not make sense), and assuming that this instrumentation routine expects a given instruction (which has been deleted) how shall I deduce what instruction is passed to it ? This is not clear in the manual.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to an analysis routine or an instrumentation routine?

Comment: An instrumentation routine will probably not be called again for this specific instruction (it may happen but it's unlikely in the given scenario)

Comment: @Heyji, based on my understanding PIN stores the instruction trace in some kind of a cache, which it executes. I say this so because, this allows Pin to add some additional routines of its own. When you do a PIN_Delete, you still have the INS object accessible in the routine.

Comment: @nitzanms: sorry I meant an "analysis routine". The sentence should be: "assuming the *analysis* routine is still set up (which does not make sense), and assuming that this *analysis* routine expects a given instruction (which has been deleted) how shall I deduce what instruction is passed to it ?

Comment: @Rohit Poduri: I know there is this cache but does it make sense (from the API user point of view) not to update it accordingly when you do a PIN_Delete ?